# .htaccess rewrite - http:// to http://www

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new to .htaccess redirection.

I am using the below code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But when i hit the URL http://example.com/folder/file.php i'm getting redirected to http://www.example.com/file.php which is wrong.

Can someone please help me with this

Help is greatly apreciated

Thanks

Comment: I have similar code in my .htaccess but I can't see any errors in your code. There are some minor differences, like `%{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]` in the first line and `[R,L,QSA]` in the last one. Is there some other rewrite rules in that .htaccess?

Comment: Please tell us first what do you want from this rewrite rule? Few examples in plain text will be good.

Comment: @anubhava basically when a user enters `http://example.com/folder/file.php`, i want him to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/folder/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

Alright can you try this in your .htaccess or apache conf file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos and some unescaped characters, but most important you're missing a needed "$" character in that *rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]* line.

Here is your code "as it should have been":

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Though, I personally use and would recommend doing it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

That should get you going... ;)